# MQ MessageConsumer Array Impl

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I am attempting to create multi queue. I have array of Queues.

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue[i]);
```

How do i make MessageConsumer as array to loop consumer list and process consumers. Since it is interface i cannot able to do it.

Please provide me suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate an array but you cannot interface.

```
MessageConsumer[] consumer = new MessageConsumer[queue.length]
```

This should help you.